# Twython - get the latest direct message

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, twython

I need to get the latest direct message from any user.

What I already tried is:

```
#importing twython and creating session.....
#api is the sessions name

results = api.cursor(api.get_direct_messages)
```

but the api only allows 15 requests per 15 minutes and get_direct_messages uses all of them... So I can do `api.get_direct_messages` only once...

So is there a way to get only the latest/newest direct message from any user? (And not using all of the 15 requests at once)?

---

**Edit/Solution:**
It turned out that there is no real solution to this problem because in order to get the latest message you have to find out it's id via **get_direct_messages()** which I don't want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more looking at twythons git shows [this page](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/examples/get_direct_messages.py) using the following code :

```
get_list = twitter.get_direct_messages()
#Returns All Twitter DM information which is a lot in a list format
dm_dict = get_list[0] #Show latest message
#You can cycle through all the numbers and it will return the text and the Sender id of each
print dm_dict['text']
print dm_dict['sender']['id']
```

some testing on my end shows this working repeatedly dspite the 15 minute limit. I have managed to return the n'th DM every minute for 10 minites

Answer (score 0):

Twitters API states that get_direct_messages returns multiple DM's but that get_direct_message() with a message id parameter returns a single message

Comment: But I want dto get the latest dms and can't get the id or is there a way to get the latest dms I'd?

Comment: You can use the get_direct_messages and select the largest id to return the latest message

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the OP's question in that it doesn't deal with the '15-minutes' aspect.

Comment: I've added a new answer using the twython Git examples to return the latest message